# Fetching AEM authored templates from different JEE Application

Tags: angularjs, spring, templates, aem

We have one particular requirement where we need to use AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) only for designing (authoring) form templates which would contain both static images and html elements like drop downs, text areas etc.

The question here is whether the designed template can be pulled to the JEE application which is separately built using Spring/Angular (deployed on Tomcat). The JEE application will be used to add user transaction data to the form templates.

Finally, the above created forms need to be published to AEM publisher.

Please help validating the approach whether it is feasible or not. If it is feasible, please suggest on how to carry out the integration part to:
1. Fetch template from AEM Authoring instance to JEE App
2. Publish the form (template + data) to AEM publishing instance.

Comment: Which AEM version are you using?

Comment: We are using AEM 6.2

Answer (score 5):

You can try out [Knot.x](https://github.com/Cognifide/knotx). It is an Open Source project which allows you to inject dynamic data into static pages.

The idea is that you store static assets such as HTML pages (defining the layout of the page, the design, etc.) in one place (a *Repository*) and injects dynamic, user-specific data into those pages.

AEM can be used to serve static content shared by multiple users and your JEE application can provide the dynamic data, as long as you expose a JSON-based API.

It supports Handlebars templates (to be rendered by AEM if you want to inject the data into those pages) but you can also add any templating engine you like.

I'm a member of the Knot.x team and we are now working on a [knotx.io](http://knotx.io) page where more examples and business documentation will be provided.

In the meantime, feel free to check out our Github pages. We'll welcome your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Templates provide authoring scaffolding in AEM like you know and allow authors to create pages (unless you are referring to AEM 6.2 templates). If your authors are creating a page using these templates then you can extract the content using any HTTP client.